# Flutter flame how to add a name tag on a component

Tags: flutter, flame

Is it possible with flame components to attach them to other components so that their position is updated when the "parent" component moves?

I want to have a component and attached to a sprite that contains a name tag with an xy-offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basic functionality of what we call FCS (Flame Component System).

All components can be added to other components with the `add` method and then they will get the same transforms as their ancestors before their own transform is applied.

Example:

```dart
final parent = PositionComponent(position: Vector2(100, 100));
final child = PositionComponent(position: Vector2(10, 10));
parent.add(child);
// It will be properly added to the parent before the next tick.
print(child.absolutePosition); // Vector2(110, 110);
```

Do note that if you look at the `position` variable it will always report the local position.

Comment: I guess then that my question would be if I can add text to the position component? Imagine dragging components onto the screen and when you select a component a text will pop up above it like a  nametag

Comment: Just add a `TextComponent` as a child

Comment: I just saw that you had already asked that question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74142987/adding-a-name-tag-to-a-component-when-selected-in-flutter-flame
Take one question at the time, and mark this as answered since it answers the original question.