# Adding a name tag to a component when selected in flutter flame

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

How can I have text appear on top of a component when it is selected? I am trying to select a component and have the name of the component appear at the top of it. And help is appreciated as I am quite lost

Comment: could you include the ui you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `TappableComponent` to your component and `HasTappableComponents` to the game to start with.

Then add a `TextComponent` as a child of your component by overriding `onTapDown` inside of your component, like this:

```dart
final text = TextComponent(text: 'text');
void onTapDown(TapDownEvent event) {
  add(text);
}
```

Comment: appreciate you man